# Quadratic Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of quadratic extensions. My book explains it:

> If the minimum polynomial of $a$ over a field $F$ has degree 2, we call $F(a)$ a quadratic extension of $F$.

So far I am not confused with this definition. But then it asks to prove the following:

> Prove that, if $F$ is a field whose characteristic $\neq 2$, any quadratic extension of $F$ is of the form $F(\sqrt{a})$ for some $a \in F$.

So now I am wondering what it means for a field to be a quadratic extension other than the above definition. I am a little confused because

1. I feel like the problem thinks that $a \notin F$ and that it is in some extension, and
2. If the element is in $F$ what the heck does $F (\sqrt{a})$ look like?

Also, my professor did not give us any other information on quadratic extensions, so if someone could point me in the direction of some useful links and/or examples, that would be great.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're asking. Do you mean, "I feel like the problem things that $\sqrt{a} \not\in F$"?

Comment: I am not sure, and that is part of the confusion. I just have no idea how to go about analyzing the question....

Comment: The problem says $a$ is in $F$. $F(\sqrt a)$ is the smallest field containing both $F$ and $\sqrt a$, which is $\{\,r+s\sqrt a:r,s{\rm\ in\ }F\,\}$.

Comment: So, then $F(\sqrt{a})$ is the smallest field in which I can find $a$'s minimum polynomial?

Comment: No, you won't find a polynomial in a field. And if $a$ is in $F$ (as it says in the problem), then the minimum polynomial for $a$ is just $x-a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused because the book uses the symbol $a$ for two different purposes. Let's rephrase like this:

> Let $F$ be a field, and let $K$ be an extension of $F$. If there is some $b\in K$ such that
>
> 1. $K=F(b)$, and
> 2. the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $F$ has degree $2$
>
> then we say that $K$ is a quadratic extension of $F$.

The problem then asks you to prove

> Let $F$ be a field, and suppose that $K$ is a quadratic extension of $F$.
>
> Prove that there exists some $c\in K$ such that
>
> 1. $K=F(c)$, and
> 2. the minimal polynomial of $c$ over $F$ has the form $x^2 - d$ for some $d\in F$

Observe that this is stronger than just being a polynomial of degree $2$. It also implies $c^2=d$, which is where the $\sqrt{\phantom{bb}}$ was coming from in the book's phrasing.

Comment: THIS HELPS SO MUCH.

Comment: Haha I'm glad it's cleared things up :)